# JBoss 7.3 getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, jboss

I am deploying war file build on Java 11 on Jboss 7.3 and deployment works OK.
Then when I am sending a request to it, it ideally should open a login.jsp which is configured but it fails with below error. This used to work fine when I was using Java 8, same war build on java 8 works fine. Nothing is changed in code. And clues what could have been gone wrong here.

```
15:16:11,435 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /lis/authenticated/identity/login: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.includeImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:397)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.setupIncludeImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:326)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.include(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:290)
        at deployment.lis.war//com.teamcenter.lis.provider.dispatcher.util.HttpUtils.processLoginFailedAction(Unknown Source)
        at deployment.lis.war//com.teamcenter.lis.provider.oauth.filter.OAuthFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:251)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImplSetup(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:149)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:111)
        at deployment.lis.war//com.teamcenter.lis.provider.oauth.servlet.JSecurityCheckServlet.doGet(Unknown Source)
        at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final-redhat-00001//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:503)
        at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final-redhat-00001//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:251)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToServlet(ServletInitialHandler.java:196)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.includeImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:391)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at deployment.lis.war//jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:171)
        at deployment.lis.war//jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:153)
        at deployment.lis.war//jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:425)
        at deployment.lis.war//org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener.process(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:170)
        at deployment.lis.war//org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.scanClasses(ResourceConfig.java:915)
        at deployment.lis.war//org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:869)
        at deployment.lis.war//org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:775)
        at deployment.lis.war//org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$WrappingResourceConfig._getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:1147)
        at deployment.lis.war//org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getClasses(ResourceConfig.java:775)
        at deployment.lis.war//org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1206)
        at deployment.lis.war//org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1178)
        at deployment.lis.war//org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.createRuntimeConfig(ResourceConfig.java:1174)
        at deployment.lis.war//org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:345)
        at deployment.lis.war//org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
        at deployment.lis.war//org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
        at deployment.lis.war//org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
        at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final-redhat-00001//javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:180)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.3.0.GA-redhat-00004//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:305)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.forceInit(ManagedServlet.java:212)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain.forceInit(ServletChain.java:130)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:63)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:251)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:186)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.forwardImpl(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:227)
        ... 65 more
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not sure why IllegalArgumentException is coming and how to resolve it. Is there any configuration settings for it

Comment: It looks like you're including Jersey in your deployment. Is there a specific reason for this?

Comment: yes it has dependency on jersey libraries